# Intuition or motivation for the definition of an hypersurface. What are we actually trying to define?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

If we have $x^2 + y^2= 1 $ then we can solve for $y$ and $x$, at least in parts. The implicit function theorem gives us the conditions to solve these things. At this part of this book (Folland, about PDE), it says that if a hypersurface is given by that definition, we can use the implicit funciton theorem to solve for some variable in relation to the other $n-1$ other ones.

So how does this definiton arise? I think the open sets $S$ and $V$ have something to do with locality of the solution, as we have inverse solutions for $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ only locally.

The definition makes no sense to me, I'd like some help.

**UPDATE:**

It also talks about hyperplane without defining it. The only definition is of an hypersurface, which is also something I don't unerstand. What is one and another?

Also, the implicit funciton theorem says that the jacobian must be invertible. The closest the book talks about this is when it says the gradient is nonvanishing, but I don't think it implies jacobian invertible.

**UPDATE**:[image]

I'm trying to visualize it. The plane should be the subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. $V$ is an open around $x_0$. If for every $x_0$ and every open $V$ we can find a function $\phi\in C^k(V)$ with $\nabla \phi$ nonvanishing on $S\cap V $ and $S\cap V  = \{x\in V: \phi(x) = 0\}$, then the plane is an hypersurface.

There's no motivation anywhere on google (there's so little about the word hypersurface in general). So the main question is: what is this crazy definition suppose to define? What are the challenges in defining an hypersurface? (what even is an hypersurface?).

Please remember that you're explaining to someone who have little background on this manifold thing etc (actually I don't even know what this term means at all) so a little background explanation would be good.

Comment: I believe that what the author is calling a "hypersurface" could also be called a manifold of dimension $n-1$. (But correct me if I'm wrong.) Googling for "manifold" should yield a lot of results. You can picture a curved surface in $\mathbb R^3$, the goal is to define a similar thing in $\mathbb R^n$. We can basically define a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ to be the level set of a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, but we must be careful to handle the details carefully.

Comment: @littleO by googling manifold I see that it's something that locally resembles an euclidean space. However the definition of hyperplane above doesn't make this clear or does not define this concept.

Comment: A good example is that the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, which is a two dimensional curved surface in $\mathbb R^3$, can be thought of as being the zero level set of the function $f(x,y z)=x2+y^2+z^2 -1$. That is the key idea. A level set of a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ looks like a surface (but we must carefully avoid degenerate cases). Also we now that most surfaces can only locally be described as a zero level set, hence the complicated definition.

Comment: The sphere is an especially simple surface, perhaps too simple, because the whole thing is the zero level set of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. But any smooth surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is at least *locally* the zero level set of some smooth function. This "locally" is what makes the definition look complicated.

Comment: By the way, a "hyperplane" in $\mathbb R^n$ is an "affine subspace" of dimension $n-1$. In other words, take a subspace of dimension $n-1$, possibly translate it away from the origin, and you get a "hyperplane". Good examples are a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and a line in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. But what is the difference of a surface and a level set? Why a level set cannot be a surface? Also, could you explain the mapping from a neighborhood of $x_0$ to a hyperplane $x_n=0$? What is this hyperplane?

Comment: As I understood, surfaces and level sets of smooth functions are very close, but we do something to avoid level sets as being defined as surfaces. What are these things we do to avoid level sets and how it lead us to that crazy definition?

Comment: I think the main issues are that: 1) Not every level set looks like a surface. (You can imagine degenerate examples. Such degenerate cases can be avoided by requiring $f$ to have a nonvanishing gradient.) 2) Not every surface is a level set (but every surface is at least *locally* a level set).  The part of the definition that says "there exists an open set $V$..." is saying that the surface is *locally* a level set of some function.

Comment: Degenerate cases would be a level set which contains only $0$? How a nonvanishing gradient prevents this?

Comment: Do you know why it maps a neighborhood of $x_0$ to $x_n=0$ and why the map is $x\to (x', x_n-\psi(x'))?$ Isn't $ x_n-\psi(x')=0$?

Comment: You should first work with the implicit function theorem in $R^3$. Once you develop some intuition, the general case is very similar. So first try to understand everything with $n=3$.

Comment: There is a big difference between $n=2$ and $n=3$. But there is a lot of material, just google implicit function theorem surface.  Maybe you can read do Carmo's book on surfaces.

Comment: For $n=3$ an hyperplane is just a plane and an hypersurface is just a surface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea: A surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is something two-dimensional, and a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is something $(n-1)$-dimensional (one dimension less than the surrounding space).

But this is too vague to be a real definition, so we must try to make it more precise.

A typical thing that we think of as a (smooth) surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the graph of a (smooth) function, $z = f(x,y)$. So in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the graph of a nice function
$$
x_n = f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1})
$$
ought to count as an example of a hypersurface. It's $(n-1)$-dimensional, since we can vary the $n-1$ quantities $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$ however we like, and the $n$th variable $x_n$ will adapt its value accordingly.

But that's not the only kind of hypersurface that we can imagine. For example, a graph of the form
$$
x_1 = f(x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n)
$$
should do just as well.

This leads to the idea of defining a hypersurface as something that *locally* (in an open set around each point on the surface) has the form “one of the variables is a smooth function of the other $n-1$ variables”.

And this is where the implicit function theorem enters. It says that the zero set of a smooth function $\phi\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has precisely this form, provided that the gradient $\nabla \phi$ is nonzero at each point of the set. (If $\nabla \phi(P)$ is not the zero vector, then at least one partial derivative $\partial \phi/\partial x_k(P)$ must be nonzero, and then the implicit function theorem says the equation $\phi=0$ locally around the point $P$ defines $x_k$ as a smooth function of the other variables.)

(When you say that *the Jacobian should be invertible*, I think you are confusing the *implicit* function theorem with the *inverse* function theorem.)

So that's what a **hypersurface** is. A **hyperplane** is simply the solution set of a linear equation
$$
C_1 x_1 + \dots C_n x_n = D
$$
where not all $C_k$ are zero. (It's an elementary fact from linear algebra that you then get a solution with $n-1$ parameters.) And this is of course a special case of a hypersurface, since if $C_k \neq 0$ you can easily solve for $x_k$ in terms of the other variables.